# Is it expected that InstanceId change on app force stopped?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I am trying out Play Services GCM 7.5. However, it looks nice to have InstanceID class. However, the instance ID string changes every time I swipe the app out of Recent tasks, or force stop the app. It doesn't change if the activity is finish(). Is it expected behavior? Shall the instance ID be persisted the first we get it?

Below is the codes to get GCM token and instance id:

```
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
            String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);
            Log.e("FOO", getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + instanceID.getId() + " | " + token);
            sendPushRegistrationTokenToServer(token);
```

Below is the codes to read the instance ID later:

```
            InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this)
            tokenTextView.setText(instanceID.getId());
```

Comment: Not according to the docs: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID

Comment: The `id` is changing or the `token` is changing?

Comment: When no swipe-to-delete and no force stop, the instance ID doesn't change. But then run into a different error, which may help you find the clue? The call instanceID.deleteToken(context.getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId), GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE) result in java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Comment: InstanceID should only change in case you update the app or reinstall the app. About the SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE error, are you using retry mechanism with exponential back-off? Things would be clear if you can post your complete code for GCM registration.

Comment: @KayAnn: I modified the original question to include the code snippets. In regards to your questions: 1). The instanceID DOES change if you swipe the app away from Recent Tasks or force stop the app. It seems a bug in Google Play Services 7.5 API; 2). The deleteToken call is a one-time invocation. 3). Let's set aside #2 and focus on #1 here. I believe that #1 is the root cause of the problem. As I said earlier, "When no swipe-to-kill-task and no force stop, the instance ID doesn't change"

Comment: Do you have cyanogenmod on the device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381091/issue-getting-gcm-id-on-phones-with-cyanogenmod

Comment: Do you still have this issue or its resolved?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this update your GCM, I can confirm that GCM 7.8 works fine.