# When should an application request for an Instance ID and registration token in GCM?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

**Background**

I am developing an Android app which requires notifications to be pushed from a web app server to this app. For this, the app needs to request Google's **Instance ID Service** for a unique Instance ID using

```
String iid = InstanceID.getInstance().getID();
```

**Question**

1. Should `getId()` be invoked inside `onCreate()` of the main activity that
   is launched by the user? This would mean that a new Instance ID would be returned each time, so this doesn't seem right.
2. Am I right in understanding that I will get the same instance ID each time `getId()` is called?
3. Does `getId()` need to be invoked from a background thread or is it OK to call it from the main UI thread? The documentation does not say that it has to be invoked from a background thread, but since this method involves connecting to a cloud service, it could block the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2. The ID is meant to be stable (not change) for the life of your app on a device, but there is a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821263/is-it-expected-that-instanceid-change-on-app-force-stopped) so I wouldn't rely on it yet. As it doesn't appear to have any other use yet, I wouldn't worry calling getID() at all yet. If that bug gets fixed it may be useful as a unique identifier for your app installs, or have some other use in the future.

3. getID() doesn't make a server request, so it can be called from the main thread, however I imagine it does some reading/writing from flash, so best practice would be to call it on a background thread.

Note that getToken() does appear to be stable across app restarts, and must be called on a background thread as it makes a server request.

Comment: I downloaded the GCM sample code from here https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git. It does not use getID() anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

They don't use getId() in the sample cause they dont really need it to communicate with gcm.

What you really need to communicate with the GCM is a Token gave by the method getToken(Project_Id,"GCM") and a GCMHandler( a broadcast receiver) that will receive data from the gcm api.